# Tensorflow training becomes slower and slower when iteration is more than 10,000. Why?

Tags: python, performance, tensorflow

I feed the data to the graph with input pipeline methods, and `tf.train.shuffle_batch` is implemented to generate batch data. However, as the training progresses, tensorflow becomes slower and slower for later iterations. I am confused about what's the essential reason leading to it? Thanks very much! My code snippet is:

```
def main(argv=None):

# define network parameters
# weights
# bias

# define graph
# graph network

# define loss and optimization method
# data = inputpipeline('*')
# loss 
# optimizer

# Initializaing the variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

# 'Saver' op to save and restore all the variables
saver = tf.train.Saver()

# Running session
print "Starting session... "
with tf.Session() as sess:

    # initialize the variables
    sess.run(init)

    # initialize the queue threads to start to shovel data
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

    print "from the train set:"
    for i in range(train_set_size * epoch):
        _, d, pre = sess.run([optimizer, depth_loss, prediction])

    print "Training Finished!"

    # Save the variables to disk.
    save_path = saver.save(sess, model_path)
    print("Model saved in file: %s" % save_path)

    # stop our queue threads and properly close the session
    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
    sess.close()
```

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing your program, but I suspect that something in your training loop is adding nodes to the graph. If this is the case, you might also be suffering from a memory leak, so [this documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/tensorflow/3883/how-to-debug-a-memory-leak-in-tensorflow/13426/use-graph-finalize-to-catch-nodes-being-added-to-the-graph#t=201612280201558374055) has a potential debugging technique.

Comment: Sounds like a Shlemiel The Painter algorithm. Are you perchance tracking somewhere else metadata by appending it / concatenating it to a data structure with O(n) insert time? The

Comment: I have post my code snippet, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

When training you should do sess.run only once.
Recommend trying something like this, hope it helps:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  for i in range(train_set_size * epoch):
    train_step.run([optimizer, depth_loss, prediction])
```